# Spring boot rest template get user by id gives RestClientException error

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, resttemplate, junit5

I'm running unit test for resttemplate getuserbyid. However it returns RestClientException error
Can someone please help?

Below is the resttemplate GET call

```
public <T,R> ResponseEntity<T> sendGet(String url, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, R requestBody, Class<T> responseClass){
        //create an instance of rest template
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<R> entity = new HttpEntity<R>(requestBody, httpHeaders);
        //make an HTTP GET request with headers
        ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, responseClass);
        logger.info("GET response for: " + url + ": " + JsonUtil.jsonize(response));
        return response;
    }
```

Below is the unit test case:

```
@Test
    public void testSuccessGetUserById() throws Exception{
        String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/users/1";

        //create headers
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        //set content type
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        //make an HTTP GET request with headers
        ResponseEntity<User> actual = httpHandler.sendGet(baseUrl, httpHeaders, null, User.class);

        //verify request succeed
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, actual.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(200, actual.getStatusCodeValue());
        assertNotNull(httpHeaders.getContentType());
        assertTrue(httpHeaders.getContentType().includes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
```

Below is the user class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> messages;
}
```

Below is the user controller class where I'm trying to make rest call to:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId)
    {
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.add("Hi");

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setName("John");
        user.setAge(22);
        user.setMessages(messages);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.xyz.provisioning.xyz.dto.User] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.xyz.provisioning.xyz.dto.User` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.xyz.provisioning.xyx.dto.User` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:583)
```

Comment: The issue is your response not returning single user and it's returning the list of customer. I will suggest check the API endpoint in rest client and see the response then process based on response.

Comment: Your http://localhost:8080/users/1 should have mapping as @GetMapping("/users/{userId}"

Comment: @Adya I've a mapping as @GetMapping("/users/{userId}". I'm returning a single user object in the controller

Comment: @Rajesh I'm returning a single user object in controller. Also I'm checking for single object in my unit test case.

Comment: Could you show the response in the browser or in postman as i have doubts if you return a valid Json which makes the problem in deserialization

Comment: @user3341564 for url http://localhost:8080/users/1  Response in the browser is :[{"id":1,"name":"John","age":22,"messages":["Hi"]}]

Comment: @SwetaSharma your controller returns list of users and RestClient tries to deserialize it to user object  so it fails it should be {"id":1,"name":"John","age":22,"messages":["Hi"]}

Comment: @user3341564 I'm returning only single user object from the controller not the list. Any mistake have I done in user controller?

Comment: @SwetaSharma try to add breakpoint in to make sure it enters this endpoint as the endpoint you show in code is supposed to return a single json object but the result is a json list contains a single object !!!

Comment: @user3341564 I added breakpoint and it entered the endpoint. I rerun the application again and it worked!! Do I need to rerun the application whenever I make any code changes?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Jackson Parser is not able to convert the response to your User class since their is skeleton difference between the two.

How about Trying below steps

1. Try Making direct request to controller from postman and check the returned JSON matches the USER DTO.
2. If JSON structure is perfect then try using restTemplate.getForObject()

If still things don't work post SS for your returned JSON and getForObject method

Comment: Hi Shivendra, Thank you for your time and all the help. I added breakpoint and it entered the endpoint. I rerun the application again and it worked!!